# Toolchain configuration for softfp using yocto

Tags: yocto, gcc4.8

I have built images for IMX6 Sabersd using yocto as shown below.

```
#curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
#repo init -u git://git.freescale.com/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp.git -b imx-3.10.53-1.1.0_ga
#repo sync
#source setup-environment build
#bitbake core-image-minimal
```

During build time it is getting the gcc-4.8 source and compiling tool chian for IMX6. The toochain is using hard floating point(checked using "./arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v" and output is having "--float-with=hard" ), my requirement is the toolchain has to use softfp.

The reason behind this is I am using 3rd party pre-built libraries, which are not compatible for hardfp. So during compilation time I am getting errors as shown below.

```
ld: error: *Executable* uses VFP register arguments,  *Library* does not
ld: failed to merge target specific data of file *Library*
```

Can you help on how I can change the configuration in yocto to compile tool chain with softfp.

I couldn't find which version of yocto freescale is using, but I could see gcc-4.8 recipies under "poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I do not know what core processor you are using.

The files that you want to modify should be in  `poky/meta/conf/machine/include/`

you could also add something like this in `conf/local.conf` to override:

`TARGET_CC_ARCH = "-march=armv7 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp"`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried by adding "TARGET_CC_ARCH" in local.conf, but it failed with error " http://pastebin.com/1Mg5pWur ", While checking config log, autoconf error was observed " http://pastebin.com/4c4EhHq6 ". Can you please help on this.

Comment: try to Clean the whole build by deleting `/build/tmp`

Comment: The compilation issue fixed by using "-march=armv7a" in "TARGET_CC_ARCH". IMX6 Sabersd board is based on Cortex-A9, missed to update this in the beginning. It seems Cortex-A9 is using armv7a.

Comment: By using "-march=armv7a" build was success using yocto, but while using this toolchain for compilation it is giving error "sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:10:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-hard.h: No such file or directory".

Comment: By using "cortexa9-neon" instead of "cortexa9hf-neon" for "DEFAULTTUNE_mx6" in the "meta-fsl-arm" layer(conf/machine/include/imx-base.inc) compiled the toolchain and with this toolchain linking issue not observed.

Comment: Congrats on fixing it

Comment: thanks, I was trying to build only gcc using yocto. I tried with bitbake-layers show-recipes(http://pastebin.com/629ArBbs) it was showing multiple recipes for gcc, similarly for bitbake -s(http://pastebin.com/TBUDnBLB). Can guide me to understand why there are multiple recipes related to gcc and whichone I have to build. In yocto, there is one to one match for recipe and package. i.e for creating each package there is a corresponding recipe?

Comment: Please write another question for gcc in yocto.